# What am I doing wrong with this interface for todo list?

Tags: typescript

My code right now is something like this.
but I am now getting An error

What I want to do is I want to declare an array which contain a bunch of ToDo but I am getting an error.

```
interface ToDo {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  done: boolean;
}

interface InitalToDos {
  initialToDos: ToDo[];
}

const ToDoApp: React.FC = () => {
//error in initialToDos
  const initialToDos: InitalToDos = [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Learn React",
      completed: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Learn TypeScript",
      completed: false,
    },
  ];
```

Here is the error log

```
Type '{ id: number; text: string; completed: boolean; }[]' is missing the following properties from type '{ id: number; text: string; completed: boolean; }'
```

Comment: Your interface is for an object with an `initialToDos` property. You did not provide that, you provided an array.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following interface:

```
interface InitalToDos {
  initialToDos: ToDo[];
}
```

To

```
type InitalToDos = ToDo[];
```

The core problem was that you were defining an interface for an object that contains a property called `initialToDos` which holds an array value of `ToDo`s,  whereas `const initialToDos` is just a simple array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning wrong data to type `InitalToDos` 
You should do

```
const initialToDos: InitalToDos = { initialToDos: [... ToDos goes here]}
```

Or

```
const initialToDos: ToDo[] =  [... ToDos goes here]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
interface ToDo {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

interface InitalToDos {
  initialToDos: ToDo[];
}

const ToDoApp: React.FC = () => {
//error in initialToDos
  const initialToDos: InitalToDos = { initialToDos: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Learn React",
      completed: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Learn TypeScript",
      completed: false,
    },
  ] }
};
```